# Screen Tearing - Lubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: drivers, graphics, lubuntu, xorg

since I installed *Lubuntu* (due to his high performances) on my **Acer Aspire SA80** with an **intel Celeron D** and **1 GB RAM** (*built in 2005 probably*), I meet a screen tearing issue. This big problem occurs when I try to move with cursor my windows for example or when I start each software. First, I thought this was due to a lack of right graphics drivers or options, so I've tried to add new **.conf** files options like those ones I saw on multiples forums in */usr/share/X11/worg.conf.d/20-intel_flicker_fix.conf* or */etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf* paths:

```
Section "Device"
  Identifier "Intel Graphics"
  Driver "intel"
  Option "TearingFree" "true"
  Option "AccelMethod" "uxa"
  Option "TripleBuffer" "true"
EndSection
```

*For sure, after all those attempts I restarted my computer and none of these instructions worked.*
Here is a command I've executed in shell to output my components and drivers informations:
[SHELL](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/655067904844365835/706593729254785104/Capture.PNG)
So, can you please help me to find a solution of my problem because I've never saw this before.
*P.S. : Sorry for my english language, I'm french :)*

Comment: Please don't provide pictures of text, I cannot copy & paste details from your `inxi` picture where as I can from text in your question.  FYI: From what I can see (https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2371684) the drivers required for your gpu were removed from security reasons and don't exist on any supported release (2017 onwards).

Comment: Hello, I'm sorry for this misstake, here is a text version:
`Output from $ inxi -G :
Graphics: Card: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] 661/741/760 PCI/AGP or 662/761Gx PCIE VGA Display Adapter
  Display Server: X11 (X.Org 1.20.5)
  drivers: fbdev (unloaded: modesetting, vesa, intel)
  Resolution: 1280x1024@77.00hz
  openGL: renderer: llvmpipe (LLVM 9.0, 138 bits)
  version: 3.3 Mesa 19.2.8`
Anyway, thank you for your answer ! But do you have an idea of which Linux OS/version would be the best for my configuration ? Thanks for your time.